# Parsing file structure based on a specific pattern

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary

I have a text file with multiple lines that are in the order of name, location, website, then 'END' to indicate the end of one person's profile, then again name, location, website, and so on.
I need to add the name as a key to a dictionary and the rest (location, website) as its values.

So if I have a file:

```
name1
location1
website1
END
name2
location2
website2
END
name3
location3
website3
END
```

the outcome would be:

```
dict = {'name1': ['location1','website1'],
        'name2': ['location2', 'website2'], 
        'name3': ['location3', 'website3']}
```

edit: the value would be a list, sorry about that

I have no idea how to approach this, can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: `{'name1': 'location1','website1', 'name2': 'location2', 'website2', 'name3': 'location3', 'website3'}`  is not a valid dictionary

Answer (score 0):

First, there appears to be a misconception about the structure of a [`dictionary`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), or, more general, of [associative containers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) in general, underlying this question.

The structure of a dict is, in python-like syntax

```
{
   key : whatever_value1,
   another_key: whatever_value2,
   # ...
}
```

Second, if you trim the trailing digit from

```
name1
location1
website1
```

you naturally arrive at a struct-like [`ADT`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type) for the END-seperated individual entries of that file, namely

```
class Whatever(object):
    def __init__(self, name, location, website):
        self.name = name
        self.location = location
        self.website = website
```

(your mileage will vary regarding the name of the class)

Thus what you could use, is a python dict, that maps a key - likely the `name` attribute of your records - to a (reference to) an instance of that type.

To process the input file, you simple read the file line-wise each time until you encounter `END`, and then commit a `class Whatever` to the dictionary using (e.g.) its `name` as the key.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact `"END"` delimits each section, [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) will split the file using `END` and we just need to create our key/value pairing as we iterate over the groupby object.

```
from itertools import groupby
from collections import OrderedDict

with open("test.txt") as f:
    d = OrderedDict((next(v), list(v))
             for k, v in groupby(map(str.rstrip, f), key=lambda x: x[:3] != "END") if k)
```

Output:

```
   OrderedDict([('name1', ['location1', 'website1']),
  ('name2', ['location2', 'website2']),
  ('name3', ['location3', 'website3'])])
```

Or using a regular for loop, just change the key each time we hit END storing the lines for each section in a tmp list:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

with open("test.txt") as f:
    # itertools.imap for python2
    data = map(str.rstrip, f)
    d, tmp, k = OrderedDict(), [], next(data)
    for line in data:
        if line == "END":
            d[k] = tmp
            k, tmp = next(data, ""), []
        else:
            tmp.append(line)
```

Output will be the same:

```
 OrderedDict([('name1', ['location1', 'website1']),
 ('name2', ['location2', 'website2']), 
('name3', ['location3', 'website3'])])
```

Both code examples will work for any length sections not just three lines.

Answer (score 0):

It has been answered, but you can shorten things by applying Python's very own dict and list comprehension:

```
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    triplets = [data.strip().split('\n') for data in f.read().strip().split('END') if data]
    d = {name: [line, site] for name, line, site in triplets}
```

Comment: This creates multiple copies of the data in memory

Comment: @PadraicCunningham True. Your answer is surely more performant. I think, it is, however, instructive at this level  in terms of brevity and readability.

Comment: It is very  inefficient, you create a list to throw away, call tuple on a list for no real reason, there will also have to always be exactly three elements or the code fail

Answer (score 0):

You can take a slice of four lines at a time from the file without having to load it all into memory. One way to do this is with [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) from itertools.

```
from itertools import islice
data = dict()
with open('file.path') as input:
    while True:
        batch = tuple(x.strip() for x in islice(input, 4))
        if not batch:
            break;
        name, location, website, end = batch
        data[name] = (location, website)
```

Verification:

```
> from pprint import pprint
> pprint(data)

{'name1': ('location1', 'website1'),
 'name2': ('location2', 'website2'),
 'name3': ('location3', 'website3')}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are guaranteed that you will always get this data in this format, then you could do the following:

```
dict = {}
name = None
location = None
website = None
count = 0:
with open(file, 'r') as f:  #where file is the file name
    for each in f:
    count += 1
    if count == 1:
        name = each
    elif count == 2:
        location = each
    elif count == 3:
        website = each
    elif count == 4 and each == 'END':
       count = 0  # Forgot to reset to 0 when it got to four... my bad.
       dict[name] = (location, website)  # Adding to the dictionary as a tuple since you need to have key -> value not key -> value1, value2
    else:
       print("Well, something went amiss %i  %s" % count, each)
```